# Reverse HexValueToStringValue conversion method

Tags: c#, hex, decimal, data-conversion

I try to reverse a method but actually I am stuck since a few days now. I somehow can not wrap my head around this piece of code anymore... Seems like some dumb sort of mental block.

```
public string HexValueToStringValue(string myString, int pattern = 196) {
  pattern = pattern % 0x100;

  string myReturnString = "";
  for (int x = 1; x <= myString.Length; x += 2)
  {
    myReturnString = myReturnString + Conversions.ToString(Strings.Chr(Convert.ToInt32(Strings.Mid(myString, x, 2), 0x10) ^ pattern));

    int test = Convert.ToInt32(Strings.Mid(myString, x, 2), 0x10) + 1;
    pattern = test % 0x100;
  }

  return myReturnString; 
}
```

I just want to have the exact opposite of the given method. I want to create a hex string from a regular string using the given algorithm.
Any help would be appreciated.

Guess this is the time to do some refactoring on this method - but I really lost track on this actually...

Comment: Why are you using code from the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace when `string` has methods and properties like `Length` and `SubString`?

Comment: And what should *pattern* be? Some inputs and desidered outputs would be useful

Comment: @mjwills I will try to provide the samples asap.

Comment: @john That's what I thought. It's some legacy code that has not been rewritten when it should have been done. Old VB code which I carried over to C# in a time saving manner - now biting my ass...

Comment: @xanatos pattern is the XOR value which is used to "shift". I don't know exactly, honestly, maybe this was some weird way to add some confusion to it to make it "safer" (bullshit of course) - again, this is pretty old legacy logic after all.

Comment: @user2649424 `test = test ^ pattern; test = pattern ^ test;` these two lines are useless... `A ^ B == B ^ A` and `A ^ B ^ B == A`. You are xorring test with pattern twice, so the result is test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored your code and written the opposite method.

As I've written in a comment, `A ^ B == B ^ A`, and `A ^ B ^ B == A`, so `test = test ^ pattern; test = pattern ^ test;` is useless, because it is equivalent to `test = test ^ pattern; test = test ^ pattern`, that is equivalent to `test = test ^ pattern ^ pattern`.

```
public static string HexValueToStringValue(string hex, int pattern = 196)
{
    pattern = pattern % 0x100;

    var sb = new StringBuilder(hex.Length / 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
    {
        string h = hex.Substring(i, 2);
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(h, 16);
        char ch = (char)(val ^ pattern);
        sb.Append(ch);

        pattern = (val + 1) % 0x100;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

public static string StringToHexValue(string str, int pattern = 196)
{
    pattern = pattern % 0x100;

    var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        char ch = str[i];
        int val = ch ^ pattern;
        string h = val.ToString("X2");
        sb.Append(h);

        pattern = (val + 1) % 0x100;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can confirm this solution! You are awesome! Thank you so much for your effort and the corresponding explanation(s) - means a lot to me!